# How to {} in format?

Tags: python, string, format

I try:

```
'TEST{0}: {TEMP}'.format("_TEST")
```

and result:

```
KeyError: 'TEMP
```

How to recived something like that by format:

```
'TEST_TEST: {TEMP}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double `{{` and `}}` to escape `{` and `}` . Example -

```
>>> 'TEST{0}: {{TEMP}}'.format("_TEST")
'TEST_TEST: {TEMP}'
```